# Get data from Mongo DB json which queried by string

Tags: php, json, laravel, mongodb

I  have mongo Db which save details about different vendors of network  devices , the database  will has data like this

```
data": [
{
"_id": "00259E-HG8145V5-435754432197F5E3",
"ModelName": {
"_object": false,
"_timestamp": {
"milliseconds": "1652710497483"
},
"_type": "xsd:string",
"_value": "HG8145V5",
"_writable": false
},
"InternetGatewayDevice": {
ManagementServer": {
"ConnectionRequestPassword": {
"_object": false,
"_timestamp": {
"milliseconds": "1652862119046"
},
"_type": "xsd:string",
"_value": "2blvl18wlqy",
"_writable": true
},
"ConnectionRequestURL": {
"_object": false,
"_timestamp": {
"milliseconds": "1652871839678"
},
"_type": "xsd:string",
"_value": "http://10.35.170.34:7547/697bce9e70e191842ee5a8272c0e7f21",
"_writable": true
},

}
```

so if user requested like this

```
InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.URL
```

I have to return this value

```
http://10.35.170.34:7547/697bce9e70e191842ee5a8272c0e7f21
```

so how can I  go through the elements in the json and return exactly the requested value , using laravel.